# How to send Ajax XMLHttpRequest with existing JSessionId

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Is it possible to send the XMLHttpRequest with existing JSessionId.

```
 <script language="JavaScript">
 var xmlhttp; 

 function test()
 { 
    execute('GET', 'https://10.10.10.1:443/server/api/hierarchies'); 
 } 

 function execute($method,$url)
 { 
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    xmlhttp.open($method,$url,true) 
    xmlhttp.send(null); 
    alert (xmlhttp.responseText);
 }

 </script>
```

- I have logged-in to the 'https://10.10.10.1:443/server/' in a browser tab
- Need to execute 'https://10.10.10.1:443/server/api/hierarchies' in another tab using the same  JSessionId.
- If I am invoking 'https://10.10.10.1:443/server/api/hierarchies' in the address bar of the 2nd tab in the browser its working fine.

***But how to do it with the code ?***

Comment: JSessionId is a cookie, right? The browser automatically sends cookies to the server -- regardless of whether the request is a regular web request or an XMLHttpRequest. You don't have to write code to send the cookie since it is already being sent. But, you imply something isn't working. What's the symptom?

Comment: Symptom is, the operation was unsuccessful. Whenever i checked the jsessionid of the request, its different from the original tab.